# Jmeter exclude URL patterns not work

Tags: jmeter, pattern-matching

[image]

I was using Jmeter HTTPS Test Script Recorder to record a login request.

Please see the snapshot, I already added the URL patters to exclude the .js files, but I still get the js requests.
Why it's failed?

Answer (score 1):

You can check that if you look at the contents of the said requests. Most likely they are `GET` requests, and most likely they have one or more Parameters. Regex `.*\.js` looks specifically for .js **at the end** of the URL. But if GET request has parameters, on recording its URL would look like `<...>.js?param=value`, so the regex `.*\.js` will not match (although the name of the request will still be the same).

So you need to specify 2 regex exclusions: `.*\.js` and `.*\.js?.*`

Comment: FYI The question mark is a regex operator - it needs to be escaped in order to match the URL query string.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it doesn't answer your question, but actually excluding images and .js files is not something you should be normally doing. I would rather use that field to filter out the "external" URLs, which are not connected to your application like 3rd-party banners, widgets, images, etc. - anything which is not related to your application under test. Even if you see it in response, these entities are being loaded from external sources which you cannot control so they are not interesting and the picture of your load test might be impacted.

So I would suggest the following:

1. In "Grouping" drop-down choose `Store 1st sampler of each trade group only`
2. Make sure that `Follow Redirects` and `Retrieve All Embedded Resources.` are turned on in the recorded requests. If not - enabled them via [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults). Also check `Use concurrent pool` box is ticked as real browsers download images, styles and scripts in multi-threaded manner.
3. When it comes to running your test add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) to your test plan as well-behaved browsers download images, scripts and styles only once, on subsequent requests they are being returned from browsers cache and this situation needs to be properly simulated

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else arriving here from google looking for an answer to this question:

**You may simply be looking at the wrong place.**

If you're looking at the workbench results tree, you'll see all requests. They are not filtered here. I've thought this was a bug with JMeter more times than I care to admit.

Instead, look inside the Recording controller tree (which is collapsed by default), where the results are in fact being filtered:

[image: Visual explanation]